Pairing of JBL Tune Flex earbuds on Ubuntu 24.04
I have JBL Tune Flex earbuds, which pair seamlessly with my Android devices and even my Samsung Smart TV. However, I don't manage to pair them with my Ubuntu 24.04.1. When I activate Bluetooth Settings, it enters a non-stop device search. I found several suggestions on the Internet, but none were specific or precise enough to help. I am a dedicated Linux user but I know very little about its inner workings.

Solved the problem myself just being careful in setting the earbuds in a pairing state.
